# Как передать id, name товара в форму обратной связи

Tags: php, javascript, html, битрикс

здесь мне подсказали, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "оставить заявку" на товаре (на данной странице представлено много товаров) отправлялось в теме письма наименование товара необходимо передать ID, NAME и тп (вопрос был о немного о другом, поэтому создаю новый). Форма открывается в всплывающем окне, через скрипт.

Но вот в письме информация указывается по последнему товару, хотя нажимаю на первый товар в списке.

Не понимаю возможно как-то по другому надо прописать ссылку `href="#inline".?idform=$strMainID`.
Также проверила, что в form_dpo.php значение idform нулевое, а $strMainID - как раз ID последнего товара.

Вопрос: Как передать id, name и тп в форму (мне достаточно просто name).

**Это блок товара template.php:**

```
<div class="form-mail" id="<? echo $strMainID; ?>">
<div class="bx-more2"> 
<a href="#inline".?idform=$strMainID rel="nofollow" class="modalbox">Оставить заявку на обучение</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**Там же в template.php Вызываю fancybox формы обратной связи:**

```
<div id="inline" style="display:none;">
 <?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/form/form_dpo.php');?>
</div>
```

**Файл form_dpo.php? где idform почему-то пустое:**

```
<?php
$mes = "Имя: $name \nE-mail: $email \nТема: $sub \nТекст: $body \nПрограмма: $idform";
?>
    <h2>Форма обратной связи.</h2>
        <form name="MyForm" action="" method="post">
        <p><input class="input" name="name" type="text" style="width:15%" /> Ваше имя*</p>
        <p><input class="input" name="email" type="text" style="width:15%" /> Электронная почта*</p>
        <p><input class="input" name="sub" type="text" style="width:15%" /> Тема сообщения</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="idform" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['idform']) ? $_GET['idform'] : '' ;?>">
```

Comment: Так он и будет пустой, т.к. все, что идет после `#` - это просто якорь.
Если мне не изменяет память, fancybox умеет открываться автоматически,
 а можно и "программно" - вот тут и открывайте URL с формой ( к примеру `/form/form_dpo.php?idform=<?php echo $strMainID; ?>`).

 Второй вариант, вместо `\nПрограмма: $idform"` использовать `\nПрограмма: $strMainID"`, т.к. в данном примере Вы просто делаете включение данного файла и $strMainID у Вам должна быть доступна.

Comment: просто ссылку с классом fancybook не прокатывает указать, потому что пропадает всплывающее окно.

Comment: А какая версия fancybox ? Первая или вторая? Опять же, что если попробовать второй вариант (я коммент обновил) ?

Comment: Да, обновили) Спасибо за ответ! Первый вариант: просто ссылку с классом fancybox не подходит, потому что пропадает всплывающее окно + в письме не передались $strMainID и  $idform, наверное их надо как-то еще правильно принять (сейчас помусолю, но надо именно fancybox). Второй вариант просто прописать $strMainID - да приходит, но ID последнего, а не тыкнутого элемента.

Comment: если в правильном месте посмотрела fancyBox v3.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, что можно сделать, если у вас fancybox 3.
Можно открывать Ваш ресурс через Ajaх, и передавать туда параметры:

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="ajax" data-src="my_page.com/path/to/ajax/?param<?php echo $someParam;?>" href="javascript:;">
    AJAX content
</a>
```

Судя по их документации, произойдет Ajax-запрос на указанный URL и результат отобразится в всплывающем окне.

Подразумевается, что по указанному URL находится Ваша форма.

Документация подробно для третьей версии - [вот тут](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/)

Если fancybox 2, там тоже самое можно сделать, может синтаксис немного отличается. Документация - [вот тут](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

Comment: Не хочет работать. Сейчас мне сложно сказать как работают библиотеки на сайте и сложно даже предположить в чем проблема.